# Error downloading and installing Java JDK in CentOS (FIWARE)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I am trying to configure Cygnus in my FIWARE instance. Following the readthedocs tutorial I execute the following command:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```

And the following error is listed:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto

Setting up Install Process

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

  *base: mirror.gadix.com

  *epel: mirror.airenetworks.es

  *extras: mirror.gadix.com

  *updates: mirror.airenetworks.es


http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/repodata/repomd.xml: 

[Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.

Error: Can not retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: fiware. Please verify your path and try again
```

Anyone have any idea what it can be and how to solve it? I'm new to Linux environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine for me, please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210448/centos-7-update-using-yum-update-does-not-work) to clean the metadata and try installing again.
RHEL documentation mentions similar [commands](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/installation_guide/install_openjdk_on_red_hat_enterprise_linux) for OpenJdk devel installation.

or run the following commands and try installing it again:

```
yum clean all
yum makecache
yum update
```

Answer (score 1):

Java version was changes in the past and newest Cygnus version (1.12.0 by the time being) uses Java 1.8, so probably you should run:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

I'd recommend to have a look to [the RUN statement in Dockerfile](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/docker/cygnus-ngsi/Dockerfile#L213). The same procedure used to build the docker container can be done to do local installations of Cygnus.